# Android L get ring mode type: priority and sound

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am developing an android application that displays some of the device's preferences such as if it connected to wifi, mobile data, and also the ring mode type: silent, vibrate, and normal.

I am having difficulties in getting the ring mode type for android L because for the priority and sound types, the type is given as normal.

Does anyone have a possible solution for this, on non rooted devices?

Comment: Are you using `AudioManager` class to check for ringtone type ?

Comment: Yes, I am using AudioManager.

Comment: Does it always return `RINGER_MODE_NORMAL` ?

Comment: Yes, for priority and sound it always returns RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.

Comment: I just found that google removed Silent Mode in 5.0 api 21.. But added again in API 22 .. you should test it on API 22..

Comment: I don't have a problem with silent mode, but with the other two types, priority and sound for which I get the same type, which is RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, however, it works only on API level 17 and above.

I am getting the value from the Global zen mode preference as follows:

```
Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), "zen_mode")
```

If the value returned is 2 then the device is on silent,
if it is 1, then the ringer mode is set on priority,
if it is 0, then the ringer mode is set to sound.

Hope it helps some other developers.

Comment: Is there a constant to get property "zen_mode" ? and if I want to compare it how I do it without hard code values, I mean like this `Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Class.PROPERTY_STRING) == Class.CONSTANT_WITH_VALUE_0`

Comment: There is a field declared in Settings.Global but due to the fact that it is hidden, I could only access it by specifying its preference name.

Comment: From the documentation:  public static final String ZEN_MODE = "zen_mode";

      public static final int ZEN_MODE_OFF = 0;
      public static final int ZEN_MODE_IMPORTANT_INTERRUPTIONS = 1;
       public static final int ZEN_MODE_NO_INTERRUPTIONS = 2; These fields are also hidden.